# cordova.getCurrentLocation() method not working properly

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm, building an Android Ionic app that is using `cordova.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` GPS break every time, I am unable to get the current location so it moves to error function.

It's working fine in lower version of Android (5.0.0) but it breaks in higher version (6.0.1 and above).

Here is my code:

```
var options = {
    timeout: 10000,
    maximumAge: 100,
    enableHighAccuracy: false
};
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position) {
    $scope.UserCurrentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    $scope.UserCurrentLng = position.coords.longitude;
    var source = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.UserCurrentLat, $scope.UserCurrentLng);
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(Data.data.geoLocation.coordinates[0], Data.data.geoLocation.coordinates[1]);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    $scope.userRestDistance = parseFloat((google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(source, destination)/1000).toFixed(1))+" km";
    $ionicLoading.hide();
}, function(error) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    if (error.PERMISSION_DENIED || error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $location.path("/noGPS");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Android 6+ requires run-time permission to use your location. By making a single request to get your current location, it is failing due to permission being denied to access your location.

One option is to use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to manage the location authorization yourself:

```
function runMyCode(){
    var options = {
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 100,
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    };
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position) {
        $scope.UserCurrentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        $scope.UserCurrentLng = position.coords.longitude;
        var source = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.UserCurrentLat, $scope.UserCurrentLng);
        var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(Data.data.geoLocation.coordinates[0], Data.data.geoLocation.coordinates[1]);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        $scope.userRestDistance = parseFloat((google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(source, destination)/1000).toFixed(1))+" km";
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (error.PERMISSION_DENIED || error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $location.path("/noGPS");
        }
    });
}

function handlePermissionResponse(status){
    switch(status){
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
            runMyCode();
        break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
            requestLocationPermssion();
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
            requestLocationPermssion();
            break;
        case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
            console.error("Permission permanently denied - notify user");
            break;
    }
}

requestLocationPermssion(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(handlePermissionResponse, function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
}

function checkLocationPermission(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getLocationAuthorizationStatus(handlePermissionResponse, function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
}

// check/request permission first
checkLocationPermission();
```

Note: on Android 5 and below, permission will always return as GRANTED.